# Application crashes while appending data on string

Tags: c++, string, macos, stdstring

I have a cross platform console application. The purpose of it is to transfer data between two peers. Sometimes packets received are not complete so we append the data into a string while the complete packet has been arrived. But it get crashed in appending data in string after sometime. Here is the back tarce -

```
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x93b77acf pthread_kill + 101
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x93bae4f8 abort + 168
3 libc++abi.dylib 0x9698180c abort_message + 151
4 libc++abi.dylib 0x9697f275 default_terminate() + 34
5 libc++abi.dylib 0x9697f2b5 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 13
6 libc++abi.dylib 0x9697f31d std::terminate() + 23
7 libc++abi.dylib 0x96980412 __cxa_throw + 110
8 libstdc++.6.dylib 0x90e23d6c std::__throw_length_error(char const*) + 104
9 libstdc++.6.dylib 0x90e4f3a9 std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) + 175
10 libConnector.dylib 0x13905228 ConnectionSocket::AdjustPartialData(char const*, int) 
14 libConnector.dylib 0x1383e0b6 ConnectionChannel::ProcessData(int, void const*, int, char*, int) + 7886
15 libConnector.dylib 0x13861ecb ConnectionManager::BaseThreadImpl() + 1185
16 libConnector.dylib 0x13861a23 ConnectionManager::BaseThread(void*) + 17
17 libsystem_c.dylib 0x93b76557 _pthread_start + 344
18 libsystem_c.dylib 0x93b60cee thread_start + 34
```

Can someone give any idea about this issue?

**EXAMPLE CODE:**

```
AdjustPartialData(char* const pData, int dataLen)
{
   if (true == packetIncomplete)
   {
      partialDataBuffer.append(pData, dataLen); // crash occurs in this line
   }

 }
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible code example.

Comment: Sample code has been added in edited post.

Comment: There may be some error in dataLen, maybe in conversion from signed to unsigned value, try printing it (or setting watchpoint in dbugger :) )

Comment: what did the debugger say?

Comment: debugger says segmentation fault. I have posted the backtrace here

Comment: read what the stack says - it is throwing length_error. That suggests there is something wrong with a length somewhere

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/ : If the resulting string length would exceed the max_size, a length_error exception is thrown.

Comment: What can be the cause? dataLen is too large or anything else? any idea?

Comment: It is a console application, I run it from terminal. That's why couldn't point it.

Comment: I understand exceeding max_size() can cause the issue but it also mandatory to avoid data loss. I guess this problem can be solved by checking whether max_size() is less than the summation the string size and dataLen. But it will cause data loss.

Comment: @Naseef - Please tell us what are the values of pData.size()  `dataLen` when it crashes.

Comment: @Naseef - `But it will cause data loss` So your data just sits in the string and you're just accumulating characters without processing the data?  That data must be used by something in your app besides just laying there inside of a string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have resolved the issue by discarding the extra data which causes the overflow. Previously I thought this will not be feasible solution as it could lead to possible data loss. But I found that TCP stream size shouldn't be greater than 65535 which is 16 bit. But found another issue when the following condition added -

```
if(partialDataBuffer.size() + dataLen >= partialDataBuffer.max_size())
{
 // do not append data
}
else  partialDataBuffer.append(pData, dataLen);
```

The issue was in windows platform it always crashes even though size of **partialDataBuffer** is much less than **partialDataBuffer.max_size()**. So, for resolving this issue I have done the following -

```
try{
 partialDataBuffer.append(pData, dataLen);
}
catch(...)
{
// got exception, return
}
```

And it worked fine for me.

N.B: I have posted my answer because it will be helpful for others who are facing similar issue.

Comment: But then you will have a discrepancy between Windows and the other platforms.

Comment: I mean your buffer is potentially shorter/bigger for Windows than the other platforms. That could result in some platform specific behaviors.

Comment: Actually max_size() also returns different value on different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

if partialDataBuffer.size() + dataLen > partialDataBuffer.[max_size()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size) then append throws a length_error (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append)

Either partialDataBuffer or dataLen are too big.

Comment: Yeah, I have considered that option, but it can cause data loss. I want to avoid data loss also.

Comment: Replace the string by a more appropriate data structure ?

Comment: Or better yet *process your data*.  Don't just have it accumulate inside of the string.

Comment: better data structure? Any suggestion? @willll

Comment: @Naseef You still didn't give information on why you're accumulating all of this data inside the string without doing anything with the data at some point in your program.  Your string is becoming constipated.  The usual solution is to clear out the string by processing the data that's there, so that more data can be added to the string without issue.

Comment: @Naseef : no, it depends how many data you expect to store, and how much memory you are ready to use.

Comment: I am accumulating this data, because the data received is partial and the packet is not completed. After complete packet received I am sending the whole packet in a chunk to the peer. And then erasing the data,

Comment: Actually how much memory needed depends on the other peer who is sending the data. He may send large packet. And I need to store the whole packet.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think you can process partial data until full packet is received as there is some determination to be done by identifying the packet type.

Comment: @Naseef Then you could have used a `std::vector<std::string>` since one lone string isn't going to work.  In this case, you need to write the logic to manipulate the vector accordingly.

Comment: I was also thinking about. Will change the code accordingly and let you know what happens. Thanks

Comment: @Naseef - Basically, you need to see when the string will "spill over the edge", and when it does, create a new string and have it get the excess.  Then this new string is the one that will continue getting the data.  Rinse and repeat.  Again, takes a little more logic than the simplistic single string approach, but hopefully you get the idea.  Usage of `vector<string>` makes this doable in a short period of time.